# Incorrect type detection in lambda with generic

Tags: java, android-studio, generics, lambda, java-8

I face strange problem. I have three simplified classes for demonstration:

```
public interface Clicker<T> {
   void onClick(T obj);
}

public final class QueryError {

   private String type, message;

   public QueryError(String type, String message) {
       this.type = type;
       this.message = message;
   }

   public String getType() {
       return type;
   }
   public String getMessage() {
       return message;
   }
}

public final class Query<T> extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

   private Clicker<T> onSuccessListener;
   private Clicker<QueryError> onErrorListener;

   public Query onSuccess(Clicker<T> onSuccessListener) {
       this.onSuccessListener = onSuccessListener;
       return this;
   }

   public Query onError(Clicker<QueryError> onErrorListener) {
       this.onErrorListener = onErrorListener;
       return this;
   }

   public void call() {
       execute();
   }

   @Override
   protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
       return "done";
   }
}
```

The problem in `onError()` method invocation.

With anonymous class it`s ok:

[image]

But with lambda error type is Object:

[image]
[image][image]

Only type cast can help, but it`s very uncomfortable:

[image]

Why in `onSuccess()` type from lambda is correct (defined in class generic), and type in `onError()` is Object instead of QueryError? Maybe I`m doing something wrong?

The same in Android Studio 2.3.3 with retrolambda and in Android Studio 3.0 without retrolambda.

[Sample project](https://yadi.sk/d/W2XzMdAP3P7a9U)

Comment: Instead of casting, trying changing the beginning of your lambda to specify the type: (QueryError e) -> // code ...

Comment: I already tried, does not help

Comment: Might help if you made `onSuccess` return a `Query<T>` instead of a `Query`.

Comment: Yes. It helps. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're invoking `onError` on the result of your `onSuccess` method, and `onSuccess` returns a `Query`.  When you invoke a method on a raw type, all type parameters are erased, and any generic arguments are replaced with their raw types.  Thus, your lambda is being inferred as a `Clicker`, which is effectively a `Clicker<Object>.`

Change the signature of `onSuccess` and `onError` to return a `Query<T>`, and your `Clicker<T>` should be inferred correctly.